# Can the university cut the notice period short?

Tags: contract

I am negotiating a position at another university. I’m on a permanent contract and a UK university that states six months notice period on both sides.

This is fine by me since I have many loose ends I need to take care before leaving, work and family wise.

**My question is:** If I give notice to the university, can they cut the notice short? E.g., can they ask me to leave earlier? Or, are they obliged to respect the six months, even though I was the one giving notice?

I don't believe they will do that, because they need me to stay until they recruit someone else. However, it would be good to know that once I ”pull the trigger”, I have a six months buffer to settle everything. For obvious reasons, I don't want to make this question to HR.

The university policy on notice periods is very concise. It says that unless otherwise agreed in writing, the notice period corresponding to my grade and position is six months from the university and me.

Comment: Please add the relevant clauses of your contract to the question, verbatim.

Comment: Actually, _don't_ add the contract here. If it is a matter of contract or of UK law then consult an expert, such as a lawyer. Actually, HR shouldn't be an adversary in a situation like this. If it is then you have bigger problems than you know.

Comment: @Ben I prefer not putting the verbatim text here. I've added the relevant text in the question.

Comment: It is not possible to provide legal advice on this matter without the text of your contract - I suggest you consult a lawyer.

Comment: @Ben, giving legal advice here is an improper use of the site.

Comment: I use the term "legal advice" very loosely here --- in any case, without relevant details, the question needs to be closed.  I see very little value in legal questions on this site, lacking basic contract details, and being answered by non-lawyers who have no idea what they're talking about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to see HR or a lawyer or both

Comment: My question wants to draw on the experience of other academics in the UK. Many of which have been in the same situation of moving between universities. I have asked the same question to a business forum in the UK where more legal aspects are concerned. However, I’ve found academia often works a bit differently.

Comment: @electrique I know an academic who wanted to leave and the uni said you have to work the 6 months. He left anyway after just 2 weeks and they did .............nothing. Why, because, for them, the poor publicity of them fighting him was not worth the loss of possible good people coming **from** industry into the department with "real" experience. However, I'm in no way suggesting you try that.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect (but have no legal standing) that they are obligated to pay you through the notice period even if they ask you to leave early.

But it also *seems* like they still are bound by a six month notice period rather than suddenly getting a shorter one because of your action.

But *suspect* and *seems* are pretty dangerous to rely on from someone who is just speculating. And, no one here can give you legal advice even with full information. We can only guess and hope we are correct. But you are the one on the line here.

I worry, also, that you have an adversarial attitude about HR. I suspect (that word again) that they are legally obligated to give you proper advice. They probably don't require all of the details of your situation to do so.

Comment: A cooment above advises against giving legal advice...